# Clients unblocking AWS S3 Content on their firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

I have a website that serves out user generated content from AWS S3.

I have a client that wants to use our website from behind a firewall.

They are asking me to provide them with a static IP Address for the S3 content, which I cannot do.

However all my S3 content is being served from one of three domains.

The client is telling me that there is no way they can unblock a domain from their firewall, they can only unblock IP addresses.

This doesnt make much sense to me. Admittedly I am a web developer, not a network technician, but on my basic firewall at home I can unblock domains.

The client also tried to suggest that I am the only website out there using dynamic IP addresses. I assured him this is not the case. Unfortunately the guy I am speaking to is acting as a go between, between me and some Network Technician who operates their firewall and network.

A week after telling the guy that I speak to that unblocking a domain should be fairly trivial, I get an email detailing some system which scans the headers of each packet with IPTables. The suggestion of their Network Technician seems extremely complicated, and amongst other things he wants to "find a tool or library which would allow me to parse the json files which Amazon publishes containing all their AWS IP addresses into simple text files, to be used with IP tables".

I am no Networking expert, so can someone set me straight here.

Am I over simplifying the situation, am I wrong in thinking a domain can "just be unblocked" on a firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client shouldn't be getting hung up about IP addresses, as these can change over time (even if you're not using a cloud hosting platform, such as AWS) as you scale to newer hardware, etc.

That said, for a hardware firewall (that is not be protocol aware, some *might* be, but it sounds as if your client's isn't), it is merely being set up to allow traffic from one network range to another (so, for example, from their internal network to your web server(s)) - at this level there is no such concept of domain names, in the same way that a telephone number *may* be shared amongst residents of a house, an IP address *may* be shared amongst many websites (and their respective domains) on a server.

It *might* be the case that your client would be better off using a HTTP proxy to enforce access control on HTTP requests - there are many products out there, such as [WebSense](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3804/how-do-i-prevent-a-website-being-misclassified-by-websense), but these services have their limitations with accuracy of algorithms.